# How Can I make these inputs editable but have them set to a default value- react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects and I need the keys and values to be editable, I was given this approach : https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-gagarin-j8cfi?file=/src/App.js
But as you can see, the inputs are all empty.

I have tried using defualtValue but that will cause problems later I believe. The aim of this is to eventually compare these values to a database later on.

Please can someone take a look at the sandbox I linked above and help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Object.entries` which will give you access to both the key and value of each property. Your example was not working because you were trying to destructure `Object.values` as an object when it returns an array.

See my working code below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-swirles-208cm?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(baseData);

  const updateValue = (index) => (e) => {
    setData((prev) => {
      const copiedData = [...prev];
      copiedData[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
      return copiedData;
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            {Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => (
              <input
                name={key}
                type="text"
                id={item.id}
                key={item.id}
                value={value}
                onChange={updateValue(index)}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```